# Simple .htaccess to remove www does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to remove the www's from my url because it's messing with my cookies and people are having problem logging in.

My url for this site is `www.example.no/ansatt/` and this htaccess does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.no/ansatt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.no/ansatt/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried every combination with slashes and without slashes. Mind that this is not ment for the whole site (example.no), just example.no/ansatt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_HOST` does not include path information.

Just do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.no$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.no/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rest will take care of itself. Also a reminder to escape literals (i.e. `\.`)